# kinect "unable to enumerate USB device on port" mounts as regular hub, but "Xbox NUI Camera" and "Xbox NUI Audio" are detected

Tags: linux, kinect, xbox360, openkinect

NOTE: MY DEVICE is an xbox 360 kinect device NOT a kinect for windows.
I have tried different linux kernels and different compilations of libfreenect, but no cigar.

The light on the connection cord is solid green, the light on the kinect device blinks green (when its plugged into my running computer).

One pecularity that seemed suspicious is that the udev file designates ATTR{idProduct}=="02b0" to the xbox "Xbox NUI Motor".  As one can see in my lsusb file linux is recocnizing the device with an idProduct of "02c2".  The device has been purchased about a month ago, so could they have changed the idProduct?? Under this guess I modified my udev rules files restarted udev, no work, then restarted my computer, still no work.

I am compiling libfreenect from github and you can see the output below.  I also tried the debian package (0.1.2).  Since "Xbox NUI Audio" "Xbox NUI Camera" are detected I feel its not a usb power issue, but I could be wrong.

test program output:

```
$ ./bin/glview
Kinect camera test
Number of devices found: 1
Could not open device
```

debug info:

```
$ dmesg
[  361.532077] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[  361.664408] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02c2
[  361.664416] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[  361.664875] hub 1-4:1.0: USB hub found
[  361.665008] hub 1-4:1.0: 2 ports detected
[  361.940144] usb 1-4.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[  361.972410] hub 1-4:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  362.668134] usb 1-4.1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[  362.762514] usb 1-4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02ad
[  362.762522] usb 1-4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  362.762529] usb 1-4.1: Product: Xbox Kinect Audio, \xffffffc2\xffffffa9\xffffffa9 2011 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[  362.762535] usb 1-4.1: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[  362.762540] usb 1-4.1: SerialNumber: A70774X04011232A
```

lsusb debug info:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 064e:a101 Suyin Corp. Acer CrystalEye Webcam
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0c45:7403 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:02c2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed ROS (fuerto/groovy) + PCL and works fine with **openni_launch** package. I'm using XBOX kinect also. Use RVIZ for visualization!

Comment: I will try this software next.